# parse specific branch in hiearchically formatted text file in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to parse an ascii text file that looks like this.

```
KEY1 VAL1
  KEY2 VAL2
    KEY3 VAL3
      KEY4 VAL4
  KEY5 VAL5
    KEY6 VAL6
      KEY7 VAL7
KEY8 VAL8
  KEY9 VAL9
```

I would like to convert this to a flat table of values from KEYs 1,5,7.  I have a very ugly brute force algorithm that loops through the file and sets flags to read values, but that doesn't appear most efficient.

something like:

```
set f [open $filename]
set data [split [read $f] "\n"]
foreach line $data {
  if {[string match KEY1* $line] ==1} {set key1match 1}
  if {($keymatch1==1) && ([string match KEY5* $line] ==1} {set key5match 1}
...
```

Is there a more elegant way to generate this mapping?

Comment: What output do you want to see? Can you rely on each sub-level being indented by 2 spaces (or a consistent amount)?

Comment: I'd like to get this into a flat table or dictionary.  Indentations are a consistent spacing based on the level of hiearchy

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```
set keylist {}
set keyset {KEY1 KEY5 KEY7}
set flatDict {}
foreach line [split [string trim $input] \n] {
    if {[regexp {(\s*)(\w+)\s*(.*)} $line -> indent key val] && $key in $keyset} {
        set level [expr {[string length $indent] / 2}]
        set keylist [lrange $keylist 0 $level]
        lappend keylist $key
        dict set flatDict $keylist $val
    }
}

% set flatDict
KEY1 VAL1 {KEY1 KEY5} VAL5 {KEY1 KEY5 KEY7} VAL7
```

This code keeps a list of keys, `keylist`, that grows (by lappend) and contracts (by lrange) according to indentation (and is completely dependent on indentation being correct). Only keys in a given set, `keyset` are considered. For each value added to the dictionary, the current `$keylist` is used as a key (the `dict` command can deal with key hierarchies, but then the keys must be separate and not inside a list (e.g. `dict set myDict foo bar 123`).

Documentation:
[&& (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[/ (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[in (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Afterthought: with your selection of keys there is actually no need to contract the key list. If you only use keys that follow a single line of descent from the root, you could use this code:

```
set keylist {}
set flatDict {}
foreach line [split [string trim $input] \n] {
    set val [lassign [split [string trim $line]] key]
    if {$key in $keyset} {
        lappend keylist $key
        dict set flatDict $keylist $val
    }
}

% set flatDict
KEY1 VAL1 {KEY1 KEY5} VAL5 {KEY1 KEY5 KEY7} VAL7
```

Note that in both examples, I have provided for values that might contain whitespace. The code can be made a little more regular if the value is always atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to parse that data into a dictionary:

```
set indent_width 2
set d [dict create]

set fh [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    regexp {^(\s*)(\S+)\s*(.*)} $line -> indent key value
    if {$key eq ""} continue
    set level [expr {[string length $indent] / $indent_width}]

    dict set d $key level $level
    dict set d $key value $value
    dict set d $key children [list]
    dict set d $key parent ""
    dict set d last $level $key

    set prev_level [expr {$level - 1}]
    if {$prev_level >= 0} {
        set parent_key [dict get $d last $prev_level]
        dict update d $parent_key item {
            dict lappend item children $key
        }
        dict set d $key parent $parent_key
    }
}

dict unset d last

dict for {key value} $d {puts [list $key $value]}
```

outputs

```
KEY1 {level 0 value VAL1 children {KEY2 KEY5} parent {}}
KEY2 {level 1 value VAL2 children KEY3 parent KEY1}
KEY3 {level 2 value VAL3 children KEY4 parent KEY2}
KEY4 {level 3 value VAL4 children {} parent KEY3}
KEY5 {level 1 value VAL5 children KEY6 parent KEY1}
KEY6 {level 2 value VAL6 children KEY7 parent KEY5}
KEY7 {level 3 value VAL7 children {} parent KEY6}
KEY8 {level 0 value VAL8 children KEY9 parent {}}
KEY9 {level 1 value VAL9 children {} parent KEY8}
```